# Laravel get plain text password when user enters the password reset form

Tags: php, laravel

While  doing a Password reset in laravel  I have a need to also obtain the  password the user enters on the password and confirm password  fields , I need this because i have to post this to another api to update there password over there as well .

Can you please let me know how I can access this .

I have  checked in controller's  Auth  ResetPasswordcontroller.php  but i cannot figure out how to intercept and get the plain text password but still alow the normal password reset to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply override the `reset()` method from the **ResetsPasswords** trait within the controller.

**ResetPasswordController.php**

```php
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use ResetsPasswords;

    // ...

    public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        // the code in this section is copied from ResetsPasswords@reset
        $request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        // --- put your custom code here ------------

        $plaintext_password = $request->password;



        // --- end custom code ----------------------

        // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
        // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
        // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

        // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
        // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
        // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,  this exactly what me look for .